# Is or isn't it a CoC violation to put a claimed ethic or national identity in scare quotes?

Tags: support, code-of-conduct

There's a certain user here who wrote about a dozen times ""Palestinian" Arabs" (in two different posts, but one was deleted; here's [a link](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/63592/18373) to the one still standing.)  Sure one can subscribe to some form of [pan-Arabism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan-Arabism) and/or invoke the "artificialness" (with or without scare quotes) of the borders in the middle East post [Sykes-Pigot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sykes%E2%80%93Picot_Agreement) and what not.

[But at what point] does it become a CoC violation to e.g. write ""Egyptians"", ""Syrians"", ""Jordanians"", or ""Iraqis"" i.e. use scare quotes whenever one refers to modern identities? And likewise, can one write ""Kurds"" (i.e. in scare quotes) all over because they don't even have a state?

Are these CoC violations?

Comment: Seems you miss the intent of exactly *these* quotes: there is a certain brew of Zionist/Pro-Israel viewpoints that claim 'any Palestinian nation/ethnicity' would be a post-1948 'invention'', intended to nothing less than delegitimize or even destroy the Israeli nation/state. But w/o context for *your* inquiry here, I'm also just speculating. A direct quote is strictly necessary to gauge either way *what* may be intended, or what *may be read into such* 'things'. Otherwise, on the face of what I read here, I'd say 'using quotes in what way ever *cannot be* a violation of whatever'?

Comment: @LаngLаngС: I've added a link to the post.

Comment: I've since deleted the answer because I think it focuses on discrediting one side of the conflict rather than on answering the question asked. Nevertheless, I think your question here still stands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code of conduct states:

> No bigotry.
> We don’t tolerate any language likely to offend or alienate people based on race, gender, sexual orientation, or religion

It seems given the nature of the Israeli/Palestinian dispute, that a person who self-identifies as Palestinian would be likely to be offended or alientated by the implication that their ethnicity doesn't exist, and so this is a CoC violation.

Comment: So, Shlomo Sand's "The Invention of the Jewish People" and "The Invention of the Land of Israel" are tabu here, but the opposite view in [this Answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/5006/6890) to "What is the historical basis of Israeli and Palestinian claims to the land that is now under Israeli control?" gets highly voted. " "Palestinians" as a sovereign nation did not exist until 20th century."