# Please may I appeal to the Community to restore my deleted answer?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I have a question about my Politics Stack Exchange post: [Why doesn't the US condition aid to Israel to force it negotiate over the Israeli-Palestine Conflict?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/63454/why-doesnt-the-us-condition-aid-to-israel-to-force-it-negotiate-over-the-israel/63553#63553)

I would please invite the Community to review and if possible, undelete my answer which was posted here:
Why doesn't the US condition aid to Israel to force it negotiate over the Israeli-Palestine Conflict? - 63553

In declining my Flag seeking review, the Moderator said: "I don’t see a reason to overrule the community consensus here."

That could be because I asked only for a review, giving no reasons; I am new here and did not realize that I had to give reasons; this was my first ever answer posted on this website.

The "consensus" to which the moderator refers, is undefined other than by the number of votes to delete.

I answered the question by explaining why it would be inappropriate to put pressure on Israel to make further concessions on top of the concessions made with the Oslo Accords, and also having regard to the breaches (which I explained) of those Accords by the Palestinian Arabs, and also the Jewish people's connection to the land, and the Palestinian Arabs assertion of their connection.

I sought to methodically go through reasons why further pressure only on one side, would be bias, and I provided sources for each point.

While the argument or points I made may be new to some, I suggest that does not make the answer wrong. It also may be a minority viewpoint, but again, I suggest that does not make the answer wrong.

Are we to delete answers mostly due to not liking them, like those in the past who removed the viewpoints of which they disapproved by burning their books?

Please if possible cause my answer to be undeleted.

Thank you for your time.

Robert.

Comment: I think you mentioned in a comment that you used to be a user on Yahoo Answers and  now that they are shutting down you are looking for a new place. Please note that Stack Exchange is very different from YA. While political questions on YA often seem to be mostly a popularity contest for opinions, SE has a very different philosophy. We want to give our readers unbiased information, not debates. I would like to invite you to take our [tour](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tour) and read through our [help center](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help) to get a better idea of this site.

Comment: Please check out this meta SE post about not putting thanks, and other taglines at the end of posts. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: I want to thank Philipp for his useful comment in which he seeks to be helpful by simply assuming about me, that I seek some sort of "popularity contest" for opinions: The predominantly hostile response to my first two answers, hardly suggest I seek to court popularity. He also refers to a philosophy of seeking to provide unbiased information not debates - My answer sought to provide information supported by sources. I do not see how the criticism of "debate" applies to my answer. By the way, if I seek to defend my answer (here) this may only look "combative", so one just cannot "win"!

Answer (score 9):

I don't think your answer addresses the question. The question asks about US aid to Israel. Your answer, while very long, seems to bring up all sorts of related matters but it doesn't address US aid.

I think that any answer to that question requires a look at the conflict from a US perspective. What interests does the US have in the conflict? The points you make focus on the conflict itself but you never put that in the context of the US perspective.

For all the statements you make, you may want to ask yourself how that influences US policy. For example, you mention a Palestinian terrorist attack against an Israeli child. Without trivializing such events, it's not clear how they influence the US decision to or the manner in which they provide aid to Israel (which is the question subject).

In the worst case, your answer may be seen as focusing to discredit a political cause. The Israeli-Palestinian conflict is a complex case that can't be solved by saying one party is right, the other is wrong and that's the final ruling. The answer seems to spend more time promoting such a view that it does addressing the question.

As such, I think the answer was correctly deleted.

Comment: What I do not follow here is that you conclude "correctly deleted" but your argument reads for 'not an answer' (but many seem to think it's 'wrong' – which would be *no* grounds for del?) while the A is deleted explicitly for "rude". Does that mean *you do not agree on 'rude'* but think it should stay deleted for other/additional reasons?

Comment: @LаngLаngС my answer here is about [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/63553)  which was simply deleted by the community without RA flags being cast. I think it's correctly deleted because it doesn't answer the question, instead it focuses on promoting a political view point. The RA flag was cast on their other answer, I'm not sure if that post is RA per the CoC, it's [an open question here](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5791).

Comment: Ah. I see a certain degree of mixup on my side. However, the different treatment on such similar issues (one concrete complaint exactly the same) in close proximity time-wise and from the same user 'against' a subset of 'the community'-(decision) makes this all the more worthwhile to compare and analyze; both metaQs need that linking. Thx for the heads-up.

Comment: Contributor "JJJ" wrote: "I don't think your answer addresses the question. The question asks about US aid to Israel.": My answer contained the following at the beginning: "Others may therefore consider my answer includes a “frame challenge”". The question was not about U.S. aid to Israel, it was about using U.S. aid to Israel for leverage.